# multithreaded epoll server: wake up N threads sleeping on the same epoll fd

Tags: linux, multithreading, io, epoll, epollet

I have a multithreaded epoll server.
I create an epoll fd, then I will have X threads sleeping, waiting with `epoll_wait()` any event from that *SAME* epoll fd.

Now my question is this: how can I wakeup N threads, with N > 1 && N < X?

Until now, I've used the Linux specific eventfd facility, and it worked pretty well with only 1 thread, but now with multiple threads waiting for the *SAME* epoll fd, a problem arises:

case 1) LT: If I add my eventfd with the "level triggered" mode, *ALL* threads will wake up when I write to the eventfd, this is just how level triggered mode works: once a fd changes state let's wake up all threads.

N = X

case 2) ET: If i add my eventfd with the "edge triggered" mode, *ONLY 1* thread will wake up when I write to the eventfd, and this is just how edge triggered mode works: no more epollfd events until I receive `EAGAIN` from `read(eventfd, ...);`.

N = 1

case 3) I've also tried with a self-pipe trick, and writing N times to the pipe would wake up N threads. Instead it won't work: its not reliable, sometimes one threads reads 2 "tokens" from the pipe, sometimes 1, or 3.

N = RANDOM

In all cases I've tried, I can't get just N=N, I'm not able to wake up only N threads, but either 1 or ALL, or RANDOM.
What am I missing? Any thoughts?
NOTE: I've also tried the eventfd specific `EFD_SEMAPHORE` flag, without any help from there.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Why do you need to wake N threads at the same time?

Comment: I want to do "remove N threads from waiting to the same epoll_fd" and make them exit

Comment: Consider using one communication channel per thread. This way you wake up threads individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [eventfd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html) manual page.

---

> The file descriptor is readable (the select(2) readfds
>   argument; the poll(2) POLLIN flag) **if the counter has a
>   value greater than 0**.

By creating an eventfd with `EFD_SEMAPHORE` flag:

> (if) the eventfd counter has a nonzero value, then a
>   read(2) returns 8 bytes containing the value 1, and
>   the counter's value is decremented by 1.

---

Use a semaphored (`EFD_SEMAPHORE` flag), NONBLOCK
(`EFD_NONBLOCK` flag) eventfd and wait with a
level-triggered `epoll()`, or a normal `poll()`.

With `eventfd_write(fd, N)` you write the *N* threads
you want to wake up.

When a thread wakes up you perform a `read()`. If
you get `EAGAIN` error, you may go back to sleep
because *N* successful reads have been done and
therefore *N* threads know they have to keep awake.

#### Disadvantages

All threads wake up (the [thundering herd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thundering_herd_problem) problem).

Comment: Thanks, I guess the question was from some time when `EFD_SEMAPHORE` didn't exist. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are mainly going to exit woken threads, as you clarified in comment, here is what you can do :

- Use ET, and self-pipe.
- Write number N into self-pipe (as you like, 2 or 4 byte int)
- A thread waiting on epoll_wait() wakes up, reads number N from pipe, if it is > 1, decrements it and writes into self-pipe, and exits
- This wakes up second threads, it reads number from pipe (by now N-1). If it is > 1, decrements it and writes into self-pipe and exits.
  ...
- An so on, at some point last thread reads 1 from pipe. This thread should exit but no more write to pipe.